# Powershell : creating a program that checks Net drives on remote machines

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I am trying to write a program that go through all my remote machines network drives and define if they are well mapped. If they are not, it will map them, and if it didn't succeed it will print me a log of the machines hostnames.

For some reason I am stuck on creating the function:

```
function checkMapped {
    $drive = Get-PSDrive m -PSProvider FileSystem
    $NetDrive= $drive.DisplayRoot
    $localhost = $env.Computername

    if ($NetDrive -eq "\\xxxx\xxx") {
        "Mapped"
    }
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock { checkMapped } -Credential creds
```

Could anyone assist ?
Great thanks,
Sebastian.

Answer (score 0):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock ${function:checkMapped}
```

But I think this won't work since you are opening your own session to do this, with no drives mapped (just checked on my own system).

Also I believe network drives are relative to the logged in user.

Try this instead:

```
function Check-MappedDrive ($computerName) {
    $driveLetter = "M:"
    $path = "\\xxx\xxxx"

    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_MappedLogicalDisk -ComputerName $computerName |
        Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $driveLetter } |
        ForEach-Object {
            if($_.ProviderName -eq $path) {
                "$driveLetter is mapped to $path on $computerName"
            }
        }
}

foreach($computerName in "localhost", "127.0.0.1") {
    Check-MappedDrive $computerName
}
```

Don't know if you will be able to map the drive afterwards : you will have to impersonate the logged in user to do so.

BUT you can drop a batch file on the user's desktop or in the startup folder to map the drive, or create a scheduled task.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the quick response, the thing is I need to remotely check the script on multiple machines, this script is directed to my machine only right ?

Answer (score 0):

this can work for you it give name and path.

```
  foreach($CompName in $Complist)
    {
    get-wmiobject win32_mappedlogicaldisk -computername  %CompName | select name,providername
    }
```